# why error for realloc ? error Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, realloc, coredump

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


void print(int *iArray,int limit)
{

int counter=0;

while(counter<limit)
printf("%d ",iArray[counter++]);

printf("\n");
}

int main()

{

int counter=0;
int *iArray=NULL;
char str[5]="abc";
printf("Enter numbers :  ");

while(1){
scanf("%s",str);
if(strcmp(str,"s")==0) break;
iArray=realloc(iArray,counter+1);
iArray[counter++]=atoi(str);
}
print(iArray,counter);
return 0; 
}
```

after inserting this numbers with sequence  : 235,225,2,2,2,365,11,2

it gives following error

```
*** Error in `./a.out': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000c14010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Formatting/indentation..:(

Comment: The indenting is still rubbish.  OP should clean it up and use its debugger to follow the value of 'counter' and see how much space its actually re/allocating.

Comment: @user1320881 No alloc needed; realloc(NULL, size) is equivalent to malloc(size).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
iArray=realloc(iArray,counter+1);
```

to this:

```
iArray=realloc(iArray,(counter+1)*sizeof(*iArray));
```

since you need to say to allocate space of what size. In your code you said allocate `counter + 1` space. *Of what?* Now, with my suggestion you allocate `counter + 1` times the size of where `iArray` points to (an `int`), which makes more sense, right? ;)

---

Check the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/):

> Changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr.
>
> The function may move the memory block to a new location (whose
>   address is returned by the function).
>
> The content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the
>   new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. If
>   the new size is larger, the value of the newly allocated portion is
>   indeterminate.

<sub>PS: Next time, format your code.</sub>

Comment: As I said in my answer @jasonjpq, with your code you are not allocating enough space. You allocate 1 byte for example in the first iteration, while you should allocate more, as my answer says.

Comment: why does it works well if i enter : 10,20,30,40,50,60 ? @gsamaras

Comment: thanx @gsamaras it helped

Comment: @jasonjpq you are welcome. I upvoted your question, since `realloc()` was something that bothered me too at the start. However format your code next time. Moreover, do not forget to accept the best answer for you, from the 3 posted.

Answer (score 1):

look at the prototype of realloc:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

its second arg is size, in bytes, and you are allocating an array of integers, you need the size of the whole array, not the number of elements, use this instead:

```
iArray=realloc(iArray, (counter+1) * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: this seem correct           iArray=realloc(iArray, (counter+1) * sizeof(int));  what do you think of     iArray=realloc(iArray,(counter+1)*sizeof(*iArray));   mentioned above  by gsamaras   it not using realloc (not reallocating using realloc)   as  sizeof(*iArray) is outside of function @fluter

Comment: they are the same thing, as sizeof is an operator that yield the size in bytes of its operand, and is processed in the pre-processing phase, so sizeof(int) and sizeof(*iArray) are the same thing here. @jasonjpq

Comment: thanx @fluter it helped

Answer (score 0):

That's because on each iteration, the realloc() only allocates one byte more than the value of `count`. I.e. in the very first iteration, you allocate one byte. But then you store the result of atoi(), which is the size of an `int`.

Comment: why does it works well if i enter  : 10,20,30,40,50,60  ?  @Jens

Comment: have you checkout realloc's documentation? @jasonjpq

Comment: @jasonjpq It doesn't work well. It overwrites unallocated memory. It just so happens that it doesn't cause immediate loud failure.